# Global Jenkins script that will be executed before a build is started

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm searching for a way to execute automatically a global configured script BEFORE a Jenkins job will be started.

My use case is, all Jenkins jobs are only allowed to start if a specific environment variable is set.

If a variable is not set, the build should be aborted.

I found the Global Post Plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Global+Post+Script+Plugin, i only need the oposite what this Plugin does.

Maybe there's another solution?

Comment: When you configure your project in Jenkins there is a section called (Pre Steps) here you can add pre-step build. You might be able to do something with (This project is parameterised) option as well.

Comment: Sorry, seems that i explained it not correct.

I need one single global script for all Jenkins Jobs. I have over 300 jobs, before each job will be started, the script must be triggered.

Comment: I don't want to configure each job, the script must be triggered automatically. Just do the opposite of the plugin. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Global+Post+Script+Plugin

Comment: There is Environment variables in global settings (Manage Jenkins --> Configure System --> Global properties --> Environment variables) but I have no idea if it is possible to automate that. let us know if you found what you looking for.

Comment: The environment variable is already set. I need a way to execute a global script before each job will be executed. I don't want to configure each of the 300 jobs. So maybe there's a plugin, but i couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to chmod my /data/jenkins/.npm and /data/jenkins/.sbt directories before running all my builds.

I could either add a prebuild step to every job (redundant and messy) or I could go under Manage Jenkins -> Configure System.

We have a Cloud -> Amazon EC2 configuration section with "Init script" - you can add what you want to run there on slave startup.

However, if you really want something to run something for every job (not enough to run on jenkins slave startup) then you probably don't want to manually configure it for each job.

I suggest you look into Jenkins DSL as you can define preBuildSteps section on any/all job(s) which can then reference a common snippet (eg. a shell script to run).

Answer (score 0):

#### Partial Solution:

Take a look at the [Global Pre Script](https://plugins.jenkins.io/global-pre-script/) plugin.  This plugin is less feature-rich than the [Global Post Script](https://plugins.jenkins.io/global-post-script/) plugin, but it should do at least a part of what you want.  It notably lacks the option to **abort the build**, but it is able to manipulate parameters or other preconditions that your jobs rely on.  You may also be able to submit a PR to add some means of preventing the build from executing.

#### Some options:

- Modify **Global Pre Script** to be able to cleanly abort the build from groovy.
- Change your existing jobs to check for a precondition (manually or via script).  This not the most scalable option.
- Replace your existing jobs with Pipeline jobs and use [Shared Libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) to bottleneck the logic.  (This is what I do).
- Generate your jobs using the [Job DSL Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/) and enforce a **pre** build step in every generated job. (This is what I also do)

#### Limitations:

Something to keep in mind for both global plugins: neither plugin provides a **proper build step**.  The groovy code executes on the master.

One use case that neither plugin will handle is a between-job **slave cleanup/sanity check**.